# overwriting product.phtml and onepage.phtml

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

A I have to overwrite two files product.html and onepage.html loccated in the folder

> app/code/stupidvendor/stupidmodule/view/frontend/templates/

I have copied the files and add my changes in the folder.

> app/code/mevendor/memodule/view/frontend/templates/

However after doing all the usual steps cache, static-content, upgrade etc my files are not pulling through. Do i need to add a preference in the **di.xml**?

Comment: Please add the full path of the files you would like to overwrite

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite the files in your theme

> app/design/frontend/mevendor/metheme/stupidmodule/...

example onepage.phtml

> app/design/frontend/mevendor/metheme/Magento_Checkout/**templates**/onepage.phtml

example for onepage.html

> app/design/frontend/mevendor/metheme/Magento_Checkout/**web**/template/onepage.html